# Select specific column from list of np.arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a list of arrays, and I want to pass the first 10 columns of each array into a scaler to transform them, but not the rest of the columns as they are dummy variables.

Each individual array is 2D and contains data corresponding to a specific column.

I have tried:

```
list[:][:10]
```

But this gives me simply the first 10 arrays, rather than all of the arrays' first 10 columns.

Comment: Are all arrays the same shape? `list[:]` is just a slice of the list, which will give you the whole list back and then [:10] will give the first 10 elements, as observed. If you can't stack all arrays into a 3D array, you'll have to iterate through the list, i.e., `[arr[:10] for arr in list]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the outer list into a numpy array too (`np.array(my_list)`)
and then use multidimensional indexing like: `my_np_list[:, :10]`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each array has the same length, try `np.stack` with indexing -

```
arr = [np.array([1,2,3,4]),
       np.array([4,5,6,7]),
       np.array([8,9,10,11])]

#Getting the first 2 column (:10 for first 10)
np.stack(arr)[:,:2]
```

```
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5],
       [8, 9]])
```